# How can I inspect the internal state of an asyncio event loop?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a Python program that uses `asyncio`. When concurrency is high, a particular part of the program hangs. I would like to inspect the state of the `asyncio` event loop myself, to try and understand the problem, which I have also detailed below. What can I do?

The part of the program that hangs looks something like the below...

```py
async def poll_buffer(self):

    while True:
    
        try:
          val = self.buffer.get(block=False)
          # hangs here
          await asyncio.gather(*[
            cb(val) for cb in self.callbacks
          ])
        except Empty:
            await asyncio.sleep(self.latency)
```

The odd part is it's not as if these callbacks are hanging on a particularly expensive bit of compute; rather it's as if they hang before the starting at all. That is...

```py
async def my_callback(val):
   print("HELLO") # we don't even get here
   await do_expensive_thing() # let alone here
```

As I said, this has been showing up when concurrency is high. I've checked for deadlocks, going so far as to remove all `asyncio.Lock`. Nothing has changed. It almost feels to me like a scheduling problem, so I would like to take a closer look at what asyncio is actually doing under the hood.

Other async parts of the program will generally continue normally, though in my fiddling, I've found ways to make them hang too.

**UPDATE**: Checking the event loop policy, `asyncio.all_tasks()`, and the state of the event loop tasks was enough to confirm that the problem did not have to do with `asyncio's` event loop. Instead, for a reason that's still not entirely clear to me, an error in calling the function was being suppressed.

Comment: Not sure about what you got there - but your code is prone to a hard to debug problem, that although documented, won't call anyone's attention: you are not keeping a reference to your tasks, just passing them to `.gather`: if the asyncio.loop gets busy (at around 1.5K pending tasks) it will drop some of those, and off they go, never to be seen again. That list comprehension you pass to the `gather` call: keep it in a local variable. (see the note at   https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task)

Comment: And since you found the problem to be somewhere else, please try to bring a minimal, complete, runable script which can reproduce the problem - otherwise, it is better to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of your specific problem, a nice way to check the event loop internals is to put a `breakpoint` call there after you call `gather` but before awaiting it. Place a breakpoint() followed by an `await asyncio.sleep(0)`, and then set a breakpoint at the core of the event loop with this in the pdb:

```
(Pdb) import asyncio
(Pdb) b asyncio.base_events.BaseEventLoop._run_once
(Pdb) c
...
```

This will drop you on the part that actually check what is scheduled in the event loop and advance everything that is complete or has a callback.